# Microphone stops working when video is enabled in a Signal/WhatsApp call?

Tags: microphone

I use Android 10 on an Essential Phone, updated to the last platform build of Android (QQ1A.200105.032). When I make a call in Signal or WhatsApp, my microphone works properly and the other person can hear me. As soon as I enable video, the other party can see me but can no longer hear me. I downloaded a [microphone test app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.greh.mictest), and it shows three options for the microphone: Default, MIC, and Camcorder. It picks up audio for all of these.

What's also strange is that if I record a video *in* Signal or WhatsApp, it records both audio and video correctly. It's only on calls that the audio doesn't work with the video. **Both apps have all the correct permissions (microphone and camera)**, and I've cleared the cache in both applications and reinstall both.

What could be causing this? How else can I debug this?

Comment: May be it is a transmission problem? If the available upload speed is too low some packets are dropped? But it is really strange that it primarily affects the audio part.

Comment: @Robert I get this problem even on my office's WiFi network, which has very fast upload speeds.